# Finding an object in Java ArrayList and changing its value

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have two lists:

```
List<Product> productsListOne;
List<Products> productsListTwo;
```

First list contains all products and the second one contains some products(some of this products have the same id), but with differen category.
My goal is to find if in `productsListOne` there is id of product from `productsListTwo`. Second part of task is, if it finds such product it needs to change `productsListOne` product category to same category from product from `productsListTwo`.
I`ve tried some solutions with `for each` loops but withous bigger success.

```
       for (Product secondListProduct: productsListTwo) {
            for (Product firstListProduct: productsListOne) {
                if (productsListTwo.get(productsListTwo.indexOf(secondListProduct)).getId() == firstListProduct.get(firstListProduct.indexOf(firstListProduct)).getId()){
                    firstListProduct.get(firstListProduct.indexOf(firstListProduct)).setCategory(productsListTwo.get(productsListTwo.indexOf(secondListProduct)).getCategory());
                }
            }
        }
```

Second attemp was with streams:

```
        for (Product p:secondListProduct) {
            if(firstListProduct.stream().filter(o -> o.getId() == p.getId()).findFirst().isPresent()){
                System.out.println("found one");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far ? And an example input-output also

Comment: Acctually `indexOf` is not needed here, you can do like `if (firstListProduct.getId() == secondListProduct.getId()){firstListProduct.setCategory(secondListProduct.getCategory());}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of the following two solutions (with/without streams). Both solutions make the assessment that more than one items with the same id can exist in the first list. If that is not the case, then you can solve it easily with the double for loop by adding a `break` in the end of the inner if statement.

With stream:

```
for (Product product : productsListTwo) {
  productsListOne = productsListOne.stream()
        .map(p -> {
            if (p.getId() == product.getId()) {
                p.setCategory(product.getCategory());
                return p;
            }
            return p;
        })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Without stream:

```
for(Product product: productsListTwo) {
  for (int i = 0; i < productsListOne.size(); i++) {
    Product listOneProduct = productsListOne.get(i);
    if (listOneProduct.getId() == product.getId()) {
      listOneProduct.setCategory(product.getCategory());
      break; // if each id exists only one time in the list - otherwise remove
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what about a `without for` solution? How is `productsListTwo.forEach(product -> {...}` not applicable as well...

Comment: Well, there are a lot of ways to iterate a List :) You can obviously switch between different ones

Comment: Do you think `productsListOne.set(i, listOneProduct)` this needed ?

Comment: In case you use immutable data and actually you copy the product you get from the list and then change it (omitted in the answer) it is needed. Otherwise if your data are mutable it is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (final Product product in productsListOne) {
   for (final Products products in productsListTwo) {
      if (product.id == products.id) {
         product.category = products.category;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should never use `==` to compare strings in Java since you are comparing memory address and not the actual string content.

Comment: how you know if it's string or long)), author didn't show what is type of id

Comment: You are correct on that. My bad to assume something like that - and seems you are right, OP is using longs :)

Comment: `id` field is `long` so `==` is good camparing in here, but yes i forgot to mention that.